# probability of a draw from a distribution of average digits being greater than y

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, permutations, average

Imagine the set of all strings of integers of length $n$. (So if n=1, it's just the set 0-9. If n=2, it's 00, 01,02...99, etc).

Now, $a(x)$ is defined as the average of digits in string $x$. So if $x=0123$, $a(x) =(0+1+2+3)/4 = 1.5$.

Let's call $A_n$ the set of values of $a(x)$ for every possible string of length $n$.

$A_1$ is a discrete uniform distribution from 0-9.

For $n>1$,$A_n$ starts to take the shape of a (discrete) bell-shaped curve with mean 4.5 and range 0-9. As $n$ increases, the density around 4.5 increases.

My question: As a function of $n$ and some number $y$, what is the probability of a draw from $A_n$ being greater than (or less than) $y$?

Comment: $A_n=\frac1n(X_1+\cdots +X_n)$ where the $X_i$ are i.i.d uniform random numbers from $0,\dots,9.$  So yes, as $n$ gets larger, this approaches a bell curve.

Comment: $P(A_n=y)$ is the coefficient of $x^{ny}$ in $$\left(\frac{x^{10}-1}{10(x-1)}\right)^n$$ There is a $\sum_{k=0}^n$ closed formula for this, but probably not for $P(A_n\geq y).$ For $n$ large, you might estimate with the erf (error) function.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas! I don't understand your comment though. I'm not sure if I just don't understand it, or if maybe I explained the problem poorly. I'm very rusty with math notations. What I'm looking for is basically $P(x>y)$ where $x$ is a random draw from $A_n$, which is the set of averages of digits for all permutations of digit strings of length $n$.  I don't know how to go about figuring it out, and am having trouble understanding your comment. If n is length 1, the answer is obvious, but I'd love to figure out a formula for larger n (including extremely large n)

Comment: Yeah, I botched the notation. It should be $P(X=y)$ in the above, where $X$ is a sample from $A_n.$  $P(X>y)$ will not have a clear closed form, I'd bet.

Comment: Interesting! I would have thought that it would have a closed form solution, just that I wasn't skilled enough to figure it out.

Comment: There is a formula, I was wrong. But it is messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will compute the coefficient of $x^m$ in $$f(x)=\left(\frac{x^{10}-1}{x-1}\right)^n=\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_mx^m$$

This expression can be expanded as $$f(x)=\left(\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom nk x^{10k}\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\binom{j+n-1}{n-1}x^j\right)$$

So the coefficient of $x^m$ is:

$$a_m=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom nk \binom{m-10k+n-1}{n-1}$$

Given a random $Y,$ then $$P(nY=m)=\frac{a_{m}}{10^n}.$$

So you get:

$$\begin{align}P(nY<m) &=\frac1{10^n}\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} a_j\\
&= \frac1{10^n}\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom nk \binom{j-10k+n-1}{n-1}\\
&= \frac1{10^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom nk \sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\binom{j-10k+n-1}{n-1}\\ &= \frac1{10^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom nk \binom{m+n-10k-1}n
\end{align}$$
This formula only works for $m=0,\dots, 10n.$

That’s not likely to have a much nicer formula.

Then $P(nY>m)=1-P(ny<m+1).$

---

Aside: I guess you can prove the formula for $P(Y<m)$ easier by seeing as the coefficient of $x^{m-1}$ in $f(x)/(1-x).$

Comment: That's great, thanks!!

Comment: Are you a mathematician? From your webpage, all I see is bridge, but you are clearly very active on this site.

Comment: Not a professional one. I went to math grad school. Didn’t finish. I enjoy math, and still read math books for fun.